# Unable to Update a column which is stored in a variable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
declare 
@columnName varchar(30)
set @columnName = 'February'

declare
@year int
set @year = 2016

Declare @abc varchar(max)
set @abc = 'Update XYZ'+' '+ @columnName+ '=     562 WHERE Year ='  +' '+ convert(varchar(6),@year)+' '
+ 'AND Category = RESOLUTION'+' ' +'AND Support_KPI = P1_Gold'
print @abc

execute (@abc)
```

On Executing this code I get this as result:

```
Update XYZ SET February= 562 
WHERE Year = 2016 AND Category = RESOLUTION AND Support_KPI = P1_Gold
```

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   **Invalid column name 'RESOLUTION'**.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   **Invalid column name 'P1_Gold'**.

Is there any way to get rid of this error and get column name correctly??

Comment: First, what error is occurring? Secondly, why are you expecting this to work? You say that the column can contain "January" to "December", so why are you trying to store the value `876` in it?

Comment: @SaurabhMishra : You are missing single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Create dynamic sql query and execute it using <kbd>[EXEC | EXECUTIVE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188332.aspx)</kbd>

**Query**

```
Declare @sql as varchar(max);
Declare @ColumnName varchar(20); 
set @ColumnName = 'January'; -- Change this according to your requirement
select @sql = 'update XYZ set ' + @ColumnName + ' = 876 where Year = 2016;';
execute(@sql);
```

**EDIT**

If `varchar` type column in `where` condition, then we should escape single quotes by by doubling them up:

**Query**

```
Declare @sql as varchar(max);
Declare @ColumnName varchar(20); 
set @ColumnName = 'January'; -- Change this according to your requirement
select @sql = 'update XYZ set ' + @ColumnName +
              ' = 876 where Year= 2016 and Category = ''Resolution'' and Ticket = ''Met'';';
execute(@sql);
```

Comment: If there are other columns in where condition too then how to achieve this? like 
    Update XYZ set @columnName = 876 where Year= 2016 and     Category = 'Resolution' and Ticket = 'Met'  
I am unable to write the other column's value in quotes(as they are varchar). Any possible solution for that?

Comment: That you have to escape single quotes

Answer (score 0):

In your query 'Resolution' and 'P1_Gold' are not the columns but these are values. In SQL varchar values should be decorated by single quotes.
so your query should be like :

```
DECLARE @Query AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @year INT
SET @Year = 2016
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(30) 

SET @ColumnName = 'February'
SELECT @Query = 'UPDATE XYZ SET ' + 
@ColumnName + ' = 562 WHERE Year= '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),@Year) + 
' AND Category = ''Resolution'' and Support_KPI = ''P1_Gold'''
EXECUTE(@Query)
```